# "variable might not have been initialized" - but I want user input to fill in variable

Tags: java, initialization

I have created a code to tell us how many reward points you get with however many purchases of coffee. It says my variable `answerPoints` isn't initialized, but my intention is to have the users input in the `answerPoints` variable and not a set answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double numCoffee;
    double numPoints;
    double answerPoints;
    String input;     
 
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many cups of coffee you bought this month");
    numCoffee = Integer.parseInt(input);
   
    if (numCoffee == 1)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 4 points");
    else if (numCoffee == 2)                                          
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 9 points");
    else if (numCoffee == 3)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 15 points");
    else if (numCoffee >= 4)     
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have " + numCoffee * 5.7 + " points");
      
    if (numCoffee == 1)
        answerPoints = 4;
    else if (numCoffee == 2)
        answerPoints = 9;
    else if (numCoffee == 3)
        answerPoints = 15;
    else if (numCoffee >= 4)
        answerPoints = numCoffee * 5.7;

    String output = String.format("You have $%, .1f\n", answerPoints);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a default value either on else condition or on declaration

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        double numCoffee;
        double numPoints;
        double answerPoints = 0; // one way of doing it or, on else condition down there
        String input;

       input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many cups of coffee you bought this month");
    numCoffee = Integer.parseInt(input);

       if (numCoffee == 1)
         answerPoints = 4;
       else if (numCoffee == 2)
         answerPoints = 9;
       else if (numCoffee == 3)
         answerPoints = 15;
       else if (numCoffee >= 4)
         answerPoints = numCoffee * 5.7;
       else
         answerPoints = 0; // YOU HAVE TO ADD THIS, YOU NEED A DEFAULT VALUE

         
       String points = String.format("You have %.1f points\n", answerPoints);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, points);  


       //String output = String.format("You have $%, .1f\n", answerPoints);
       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output );
 }
}
```